# UpdatePanel inside JQuery Dialog Not Updating

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, updatepanel

I have a control which has several update panels on it. The control is then loaded into a (non-modal) JQueryUI dialog. In most cases, this works fine -- I can get the buttons on the control to fire and update portions of the control which are ultimately being displayed to the user as part of a JQueryUI dialog.

The problem comes when things get mixed together. On my main page there is a link to reopen the main dialog and recall of its previous state. Ultimately this calls a simple javascript:

```
function openDialog(id, name)
{
   // Tell asp.net code behind what we're trying load
   var formField = document.getElementById('<%= userControl1.idField.ClientID %>');
   formField.value = id;

   // Tell asp.net to refresh the contents
   __doPostBack('<%= userControl1.documentUpdatePanel.ClientID %>', '');

   $("#dialog-editDoc").dialog
        ({
            width: 400,
            resizable: true,
            open: function ()
            {
                // This is impotant for ASP.NET
                $(this).parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
                $(this).dialog("option", "title", "Editing Document - " + name);
            }
        });

}
```

This appears to work fine, I get the `PageLoad()` event in my user control's code behind, and I am able to change the contents appropriately. However, when the dialog shows up, the contents that were just changed as part of `PageLoad()`.

What's strange is that the buttons on the user control are clicked, the events fire correctly and I am able to make changes while the dialog is being shown. It seems there is some difficulty getting the dialog to "change state" before (or as it is being) shown.

So, does anyone know of a way around this? Other things I have tried:

- Moving `__doPostBack(...)` into the  `open:` function -- same problem.

Edit:

Here's how the user control is loaded on the page (it's not in an update panel, the update panel is inside the doc editor control):

```
<div id="dialog-editDoc" class="dialogContent" title="{Context Sensitive}">
    <mylib:DocEditor ID="userControl1" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debugging, I determined the code linked above will work in all situations *except* when the link/button/... that fires the JS event is insdide an `UpdatePanel`.

So how did I get around the problem. Well, since the button was already inside an `UpdatePanel` I could attach to it's normal `OnClick` event without fear of having the whole page refresh. In the `OnClick` event, I simply used the "standard" way of calling a JS function from a code-behind via `RegisterStartupScript`, e.g.,:

```
string JSFunction = "openDialog('id_goes_here','name_goes_here')";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page), "runJS", jsFunction, true);
```

Strangely this seems to work. Not exactly sure why. Ultimately, the JS still does all the work, and the call structure (observed via the debugger) is the same.

If anyone can explain why the method described above works, but not just calling the JS function directly via `OnClientClick`, I'll accept/upvote their answer instead of mine.